# How to embed arbitrary text/data in SVG files?

Tags: xml, svg, tikz

I have created a diagram with tikz and pdflatex and converted it to SVG with inkscape. I want to embed the latex code into the .svg file so that others are able to regenerate/modify it. The problem is that tikz code contains lots of `--` (to draw lines) and this makes it impossible to add the code as is as an XML comment to SVG (see [this other question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198481/why-cant-an-xml-comment-contain-two-hyphens)).

I was thinking about adding it as CDATA but failed so far (i.e. http://validator.w3.org/ does not validate it).

Here is a MWE of what Carlo Cannas suggested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1">
    <metadata>
        <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" encoding="TeX">
            blah --
        </annotation>
    </metadata>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may include it in a [`metadata`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/metadata.html#MetadataElement) element, as normal text or using other elements.

I'd suggest to include the code in a MathML [`annotation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/chapter4.html#contm.annotation) element, with the appropriate `encoding` attribute. MathML namespace URI is `http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML`, so at the end the code will be something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="[...SVG namespace URI here...]">
    <metadata>
        <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" encoding="TeX">
            <!-- TeX code here (obviously not in this comment, remove this whole line and write it in a CDATA section or as character data, as you wish) -->
        </annotation>
    </metadata>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. The validator gives me `MathML element annotation not allowed as child of SVG element metadata in this context.` though (see edit)

Comment: @stefanct That's because the validator is trying to validate foreign namespace elements. If you try to validate the example in the specifications you'll get similar errors. However, don't worry: your document is ok even if the validator gives you those errors.

Comment: Yes, I think you right. The error message seemed so indisputable... :) thanks!